# Method that checks if a parameter has occurred in a hashmap(Key)

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two parameters represent two case-sensitive words that might have been found in a document. I need a method that must return true if the first parameter has occurred at least once in the document and was immediately followed at least once by the second word. Otherwise it must return false.

Here is my code.

```
public boolean nextTo(String firstInput, String secondInput) {
Iterator it = Words.keySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext() == true)
    {
        it.next();

        if (Words.containsKey(firstInput))
        {
            if(Words.higherKey(secondInput))

            {
                return true;
            }

        }

    }
    return false;
```

Comment: From what I understood, Words is a collection of all words found in the document, therefore you can only use the Words collection for the first key, but have to check every occurrence of the word and the word after in the document. Otherwise, you don't have ensured the order.

Comment: so how do i do that/ implement it?

Comment: `hasNext()` is already a boolean value. Don't compare to `true`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the iterator loop, when you never use the values found while iterating, i.e. you never use the value returned by `next()`?

Comment: What are the map values?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Represent the document as a `String[]` and just iterate the words in the document.  When you see `firstInput`, test that the next word is `secondInput`.

Solution 2:

Create a reverse index for the document; i.e. a `Map<String, int[]>` where the `String` keys are the words and the `int[]` values contain the indexes for each occurrence of the word in the document.

Populate the reverse index from the document.

Then, to find if `firstInput` followed by `secondInput`:

```
int[] fi = reverseIndex.get(firstInput);
int[] si = reverseIndex.get(secondInput);

if (fi == null || si == null) {
    return false;
}
for (int i = 0; i < fi.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < si.length; j++) {
        if (fi[i] == si[j] - 1) {
           return true;
        }
    }
}
return false.
```